# can I assemble instruction using pseudo register?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, att, machine-code

I am studying reassembleable disassembly.
It is about changing the format of disassembly (generated by `objdump`) into a form that can be reassembled.

The problem was..
When I disassembled the binaries using `objdump`,
I saw following instructions:
(This is a pseudo instruction added by `GCC`, which is acting as a multi-byte nop.)

```
80493ac:   8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
80494b9:   8d b4 26 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
8049b19:   8d bc 27 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi
```

To reassemble it, I changed the format of instruction like below:

```
.global main
main:
 lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
 lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
 lea    0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi
```

I saved the above file and tried to assembled it into binary.
However, it failed. The results were as follows:

```
$ gcc -o eiz_ex eiz_ex.s -m32
eiz_ex.s: Assembler messages:
eiz_ex.s:3: Error: bad register name '%eiz'
eiz_ex.s:4: Error: bad register name '%eiz'
eiz_ex.s:5: Error: bad register name '%eiz'
```

I can just substitute the instruction contains pseudo instruction to `nop` to make working binary.
ex) change instruction `0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi` to `nop`

However, I want to assemble it and
get the same byte pattern as the original binary. 
For example
`lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi` --*assemble*--> `8d 74 26 00`

Do you have any idea to reassemble it??

Comment: clang accepts `lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi`  (It doesn't accept a `{disp32}` before the mnemonic, though).  So the instruction-length won't be the same.

Comment: You really want actual long NOPs, rather than LEA.  And if you want to change anything in the asm, you want to align to (usually) 16-byte boundaries rather than preserving the exact padding length.  So if it's not too big to manually edit stuff, remove padding or replace it with a `.p2align 4` directive.  (Or `.p2align 4,12` to only pad if the distance is less than 12 bytes.)

Comment: Have a look at what Agner Fog's `objconv` disassembler does: it's written to create asm that you can reassemble.  I haven't used its AT&T output mode, but it does have one.   http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv

Comment: FYI, `clang` seems to support this, starting from around version 3.4.

Comment: @PeterCordes Your advice was very helpful to my situation. Thank you very much!